# WordPress target only one post on hover

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress theme. Using jQuery or just CSS, on hover how do I target only the elements in that post without affecting other posts? More specifically, I want to display some buttons over the image on hover, but not on images on other posts obviously.

This is a single post here, the code inside the loop. The buttons are inside the .actions div.

```
<div class="post-holder">
    <div class="post-image">
        <div class="post-image-sizer">
            <?php 
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment','numberposts' => 1,'post_parent' => $post->ID );
            $images = get_posts($args);
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($images[0]->ID, $size='attached-image'); 
            ?>

            <div class="actions">
                <div class="btn download"></div>
                <div class="btn expand"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-info">
        <div class="post-date">
            <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS hides the buttons in the beginning:

```
.btn {
    display: none;
}
```

So, jQuery or pure CSS, how do I target only the ".btn"s on the one post hovered? It will have a 500ms animation, so just put it in there if you like. CSS would of course be nice, just don't know how to or if it's possible, this targeting with it. The hover trigger element is the .post-image div so that the hover is not lost when hovered over the buttons themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS(3)**

You can get the effect you want with the default `:hover` and css3 transitions:

```
.post-holder .btn {
  visibility:hidden; // display:none breaks transitions
  height:0;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}


.post-holder:hover .btn {
  visibility:visible;
  height:auto;
  opacity:1;
}
```

<kbd>[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fuHqb)</kbd>

**jQuery**

You can use jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) methods:

```
$(function(){
  $('.post-holder').hover( function(){
    $(this).find('.btn').stop().toggle('500');
  });
});
```

<kbd>[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ikLpm)</kbd>

I will leave tweaking the "fanciness" of the transitions up to you ; )

Comment: Obviously you meant visibility:visible, not display:visible :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to target the ID of the post rather than a class common to posts in general. None of the IDs are shown in your question so I can't give you specifics, but to target it you could use something like the following

```
.btn#targetID:hover {
    /* Your CSS here */
}
```

Comment: does this help, here is the source from the page generated, it's local so can't show online now, but here http://pastebin.com/F6YvKEN7 here is also how it looks if it helps: http://cl.ly/image/3U1k2J33133x , first image being hovered, buttons should then become visible